# Are obs stream being closed automatically by GetxControllers?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-get

I am using the following package https://pub.dev/packages/get. Do I need to close my .obs in the onClose of a GetxController? I can't find anything about this in the docs. And looking at my memory it appears that the are being destroyed automatically.

Comment: Did anyone find out about this?

Comment: I haven't. Would like to know still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my understanding of GetX + Flutter so far...

No, you shouldn't have to remove .obs in the `close()` method of GetxControllers.  Disposal of observables from a Controller are done automatically when the Controller is removed from memory.

**GetX disposes/removes GetxControllers (and their observables) when the widget in which they are contained are popped off the widget stack / removed from the widget tree** (by default, but can be overridden).

You can see this in the override of `dispose()` methods of various Get widgets.

Here's a snippet of `dispose()` that's run when `GetX` widgets are popped/removed:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (widget.dispose != null) widget.dispose(this);
    if (isCreator || widget.assignId) {
      if (widget.autoRemove && GetInstance().isRegistered<T>(tag: widget.tag)) {
        GetInstance().delete<T>(tag: widget.tag);
      }
    }
    subs.cancel();
    _observer.close();
    controller = null;
    isCreator = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

When you use Bindings or `Get.to()` you're using `GetPageRoute`'s which do cleanup by Route names:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (Get.smartManagement != SmartManagement.onlyBuilder) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => GetInstance()
          .removeDependencyByRoute("${settings?.name ?? routeName}"));
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```

## Test App

Below is a test App you can copy/paste into Android Studio / VSCode and run to watch the debug or run window output for GETX lifecycle events.

GetX will log the creation & disposal of Controllers in and out of memory.

[image: GetX Output Log]

The app has a HomePage and 3 ChildPages using Get Controllers in 3 ways, all which remove itself from memory:

1. GetX / GetBuilder
2. Get.put
3. Bindings

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  // MyCounterBinding().dependencies(); // usually where Bindings happen
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'GetX Dispose Ex',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetX Dispose Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('GetX/Builder Child'),
              onPressed: () => Get.to(ChildPage()),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get.put Child'),
              onPressed: () => Get.to(ChildPutPage()),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Binding Child'),
              onPressed: () => Get.to(ChildBindPage()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// GETX / GETBUILDER
/// Creates Controller within the Get widgets
class ChildPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetX Dispose Test Counter'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('This is the Child Page'),
            GetX<ChildX>(
              init: ChildX(),
              builder: (cx) => Text('Counter: ${cx.counter}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
            ),
            GetBuilder<ChildX>(
              init: ChildX(),
              builder: (cx) => RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Increment'),
                onPressed: cx.inc,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// GET.PUT
/// Creates Controller instance upon Build, usable anywhere within the widget build context
class ChildPutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  //final ChildX cx = Get.put(ChildX()); // wrong place to put  
  // see https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/818#issuecomment-733652172

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ChildX cx = Get.put(ChildX());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetX Dispose Test Counter'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('This is the Child Page'),
            Obx(
              () => Text('Counter: ${cx.counter}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Increment'),
              onPressed: cx.inc,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCounterBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => ChildX(), fenix: true);
  }
}

/// GET BINDINGS
/// Normally the MyCounterBinding().dependencies() call is done in main(),
/// making it available throughout the entire app.
/// A lazyPut Controller /w [fenix:true] will be created/removed/recreated as needed or
/// as specified by SmartManagement settings.
/// But to keep the Bindings from polluting the other examples, it's done within this
/// widget's build context (you wouldn't normally do this.)
class ChildBindPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyCounterBinding().dependencies(); // just for illustration/example

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetX Dispose Test Counter'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('This is the Child Page'),
            Obx(
                  () => Text('Counter: ${ChildX.i.counter}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Increment'),
              onPressed: ChildX.i.inc,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class ChildX extends GetxController {
  static ChildX get i => Get.find();
  RxInt counter = 0.obs;

  void inc() => counter.value++;
}
```

## Notes

#### Get.to vs. Navigator.push

When using `Get.put()` in a child widget be sure you're using `Get.to()` to navigate to that child rather than Flutter's built-in `Navigator.push`.

GetX wraps the destination widget in a `GetPageRoute` when using `Get.to`.  This Route class will dispose of Controllers in this route when navigating away / popping the widget off the stack.  If you use `Navigator.push`, GetX isn't involved and you won't get this automatic cleanup.

**Navigator.push**

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ChildPutPage())),
```

**Get.to**

```
onPressed: () => Get.to(ChildPutPage()),
```

Answer (score 2):

Based from the code of the super implementation of onClose, by default it does nothing currently.

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/7146b6a53c0648104e4f623385deaff055e0036a/lib/get_instance/src/lifecycle.dart#L56

And from the comments, it says:

```
  /// Called before [onDelete] method. [onClose] might be used to
  /// dispose resources used by the controller. Like closing events,
  /// or streams before the controller is destroyed.
  /// Or dispose objects that can potentially create some memory leaks,
  /// like TextEditingControllers, AnimationControllers.
  /// Might be useful as well to persist some data on disk.
  void onClose() {}
```

from that I think you need to manually close your streams in YourController::onClose() override function.

Comment: I think it is only when you bind a stream but if you use a worker such as ever() or once() it apprears to handdle it automatically. You can just call myObsVarialble.close()

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can use obs safely when using GetWorkers. Run this code and you'll notice that when you click the buttons a few time there will only be one print per page switch.

```
void main(){
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(home: TestWidget(),));
}

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('next'),
        onPressed: () => Get.to<SomeWidget>(SomeWidget()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  RxBool isSubscribed = false.obs;

  SomeWidget() {
    ever(isSubscribed, (_) => print('test'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('back'),
        onPressed: () {
          isSubscribed.value = !isSubscribed.value;
          Get.back();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```